# My custom listView with Checkboxes and imageViews Strange Behaviour

Tags: android, listview

I had a `ListView` with images that are loading by using `ImageLoader`(framework) and checkbox for each image.I had a adapter that is extending `BaseAdapter` for this `ListView`,when i'm checking one of the checkbox and scrolling it then  i see other checkboxes which are automatically checked. Is there any way to resolve my issue. Please someone give me a clue or example.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the rows are being re-used, so you need to set some attribute for each row telling it whether that row is checked or not. And then make "if and else" statement in your `getView()` to look if that row is checked or not, and if it is just check it, otherwise leave it unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an array of booleans where you keep your checked state for every position in the list. ListView recreates list elements on scroll, so your checks could be messed up. This means that you have to check if boolean value for position of the element you're instantiating is true and then use checkBox.setChecked(true), or checkBox.setChecked(false).

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

```
Set<String> bs = new HashSet(String);

String[] bid;
```

And write this in you getView method, Take it as a template. Not as a solution

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            row = convertView;
            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = vi.inflate(R.layout.your_listview,null);
            }

            check = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.your_checkboxid);
            check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        bs.add(bid[position]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(bs.contains(bid[position]))
                        {
                            bs.remove(bid[position]);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            if(bs.contains(bid[position]))
            {
                check.setChecked(true);
            }
            else
            {
                check.setChecked(false);
            }   
            return row;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,I had one more query that is,how to restrict the user to check 5 checkboxes and disable or make invisible other checkboxes in the list view and whenever user uncheck's one of the five checkboxes that was previous checked should make checkbox enabled or visible again.

Comment: It smells like a new question. I suggest you to put this in a new thread and if the above answer solved your checkbox query then mark this answer as accepted.